# Purpose of param in do-loops

Tags: prolog

I'm learning Prolog from "Learn Prolog" book. I'm quite newbie in Prolog.

I have knowledge base:

```
 transpose(Matrix, Transpose) :-
          dim(Matrix, [R, C]),
          dim(Transpose, [C, R]),
          ( foreachelem(E,Matrix,[I,J]),
             param(Transpose)
            do subscript(Transpose,[J, I], E ) ).
```

Run:

```
Matrix=[]([](11,12),[](21,22),[](31,32)),transpose(Matrix,Transpose).
```

Result:

```
Matrix = []([](11, 12), [](21, 22), [](31, 32))
Transpose = []([](11, 21, 31), [](12, 22, 32))
```

I do not understand the purpose of `param`.
Help me understand. Thanks.

Comment: doesn't seem Prolog. It's a dialect (maybe B-Prolog)?

Comment: @chac: It's ECLiPSe, so a dialect of Prolog.

Comment: @chac: I'm sorry for ambiguous information,It's ECLiPSe.

Comment: @chac: The syntax is valid ISO Prolog (provided an operator declaration for (do)/2 is present). `[](X) == '[]'(X).`

Comment: @false: yes, I tried it in SWI-Prolog. I had never seen before the [](...) syntax, but was aware the [] it's an atom. My old Prolog interpreter, naively implemented after reading Clocksin-Mellish, doesn't comply with such rules.

Comment: @chac: Already DECsystem 10 permitted `[ /* a comment within */ ](X)`. There are tokens like `'['` and `']'` which only then form the functor.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `Transpose` is listed in `param` so that it is available inside the `do/2` loop.

Consider the `do/2` calls as macros. The ECLiPSe compiler transforms them into auxiliary predicates.

Your predicate `transpose/2` thus becomes something like this:

```
transpose(Matrix, Transpose) :-
      dim(Matrix, [R, C]),
      dim(Transpose, [C, R]),
      do__1(..., Transpose).

do__1(..., Transpose) :- !.
do__1(..., Transpose) :- 
    ForelemGoals, 
    subscript(Transpose,[J, I], E ), 
    do__1(..., Transpose).
```

How the `do__1` predicate exactly looks like for `foreachelem` loops, I don't know. But in any case are all variables in the `param` entry added to the variables in the `do__1` heads, so that they are available inside the auxiliary predicates. Without this, the `Transpose` variable inside the `do/2` loop of your `transpose/2` predicate would have no connection to the `Transpose` variable outside the loop.

**Edit**: A good introduction into `do/2`-loops in ECLiPSe, including the very same `transpose/2` example, can be found in chapter 7 of "Constraint Logic Programming using ECLiPSe" by Krzysztof Apt and Mark Wallace.

Comment: @false: As I said, I don't know by heart how the transformation looks like, and although the generated code is traceable, I can't get the source code listed. The `do__1` code is adapted from the ECLiPSe manual, and the code there includes the cut. I could ask Joachim, though, if it really matters. OTOH, I don't see how a cut in the recursion anchor of `do__1` can be a red one.

Comment: @twinterer: I was wrong with my claim: `dim(M,[R,C])` produces an error with `M` uninstantiated. So no red cut here. I was thinking too much of `foreach(a,As)do true` which incorrectly yields a single answer/solution, when infinitely many are expected.

Comment: @false: I would say incomplete rather than incorrect, but yes. You can achieve completeness by adding a `length/2` call: `length(As, N),( foreach(a,As), count(_I, 1, N) do true )`, though. In practice, I rarely use do-loops as generators in combination with backtracking (and usually favour speed over completeness anyway), so I never realized the possible 'redness' of the cut.

Comment: @twinterer: Writing such programs manually, is extremely rare. But generating them as en explanation for failure - in particular when having constraints - is a case where such problems show. There you really need to rely on monotonicity.

Comment: @false: I asked - the decision to make this cut red in some modes was deliberate, a compromise. Ideally, the number of iterations for a loop should be deterministic, analogous to the condition in `If->Then;Else`. However, since there are multi-mode specifiers like `foreach(?,?)`, which work as iterators or generators, the cut was introduced to achieve determinism. So I guess do-loops should only be used with predetermined number of iterations, though the manual doesn't state this. Also, patterns like `foreach(X,L),fromto(false,_,F,true) do DoTillTrue` allow collecting input of unknown length.

Comment: @twinterer: There is more to that: `for(_,1,3),for(_,1,2)do true` loops.

Comment: @false: of course it loops, as would any recursive predicate with two incompatible but conjunct termination conditions. I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @twinterer: recursive predicates where such things discussed happen are not steadfast - thus very brittle to use. Maybe take: `for(I,1,1), foreach(I,L)do true` as a more convincing example, This should be steadfast w.r.t. `L`. But it loops for certain values of `L`, whereas it terminates for `L` being free.

Comment: @false: do-loops are simple macros, always generating two clauses: a recursion anchor with just a cut as body, and another clause with maintenance code and loop body. All iteration specifiers must specify the same number of loops, since the termination conditions are AND-ed. If they don't, e.g. if in your example L is bound to a list of indetermined length > 1 ([_ , _ |_]), you get infinite recursion. Yes, this is sometimes brittle, and we could wish for more checks, but the onus is on the programmer. Personally, I prefer them to "traditional" recursion - clearer and easier to refactorize.